# TwoWay manual binding on Class property which is again a class

Tags: wpf, data-binding, dependency-properties

In this below code, initially text field shows text as "XYZ", but when I click on button which is changing FlatName property of Address. This is not reflecting in UI, that is text field is not updating.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp5.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp5"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="132,184,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click"/>

<TextBox Text="{Binding Address.FlatName, Mode=TwoWay}"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="199,134,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>


    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**C# Code Snippet:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApp5
{

    public class Address
    {
        public string FlatName
        {
            get; set;

        } = "XYZ";

    }

    public class Person : DependencyObject
    {

        public string Name
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(NameProperty); }
            set { SetValue(NameProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Name.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty NameProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Name",
                typeof(string),
                typeof(Person),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                "",
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure
                ));


        public Address Address
        {
            get { return (Address)GetValue(AddressProperty); }
            set { SetValue(AddressProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Name.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty AddressProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Address",
                typeof(Address),
                typeof(Person),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                new Address(),
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure
                ));



    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        Person person = new Person();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = person;
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            person.Address.FlatName = "ABC";
        }

        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //string Area = person.Address.FlatName;
        }
    }
}
```

If you see I have person class which is DataContext for my Page. There is a property on Person class called ***Address*** this is very important where I have one property called FlatName which is Bindind with TextField of form. If I update FlatName using APIs which is not updating UI.

Answer (score 1):

`Address` should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`:

```
public class Address : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _flatName = "XYZ";
    public string FlatName
    {
        get { return _flatName; }
        set { _flatName = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

This is required for the target property to be refreshed "automatically" when you set the source property.

Comment: I missed that aspect.

Answer (score 0):

I've come across this before, it's because you're using a dot in your binding.  Try setting the datacontext of the TextBox to Address and then just binding to flat name in the Text Property.